# Log in a user based on value Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, controller

I am verifying user's account via email and I want to redirect the user directly to home page after account is verified.

The issue I am having is that I am not sure how to actually log in the user using `login` function.

```
class VerificationController extends Controller {

    public function verify($token){ 

        User::where('email_token',$token)->firstOrFail()->verified();
        // auth()->login($user); works if $user exists
        return redirect('/home');
    }
}
```

Can I log in the user based on the `email_token`? I tried but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Comment: If you're using the basic `Authentication` that comes with Laravel, there's a method for handling this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users. If you're using a package like Sentry or Sentinel, they have their own functions like https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0#sentinel-login. Please provide the specific issue you are facing here. Are you trying to log in a user for access from anywhere? Etc etc.

Comment: Can you explain why it doesn't seem to work, what are you expecting?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz it doesn't work because it doesn't log in the user. I can't seem to create an instance of user to log it in. `Auth::user()` doesn't work because user is not logged in and when I do `$user = User::find($token);` it remains blank.

Comment: @Nik the `find` method by design uses the 'id' column of the model or table, that's why I suppose you got no result. You should `where` method instead to match the targeted field.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin I tried this one as well `$user = DB::table('users')->where('email_token', $token)->first()->email;` but it still empty.

Comment: Are you sure the `email_token` matches with the token you are passing? I will suggest you should manually retrieve that token and compare it directly using queries, then you can know what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right way. You just need to get the `User` instance and pass it to the `login` Method of the `Auth` class. I've made an example controller for you to show how this could be done.

```
class VerificationController extends Controller 
{
    public function verify($token)
    {
        // Fetch the user by the email token from the database.
        // #firstOrFail returns the first matching user or aborts 
        // the request with a 404 error.
        $user = User::where('email_token', $token)->firstOrFail();

        // Activate your user or whatever this method does.
        $user->verified();

        // Logs the Client who did this web request into the
        // User account fetched above in.
        Auth::login($user);

        // Redirect to wherever you want.
        return redirect('/home');
    }
}
```

---

Read more about authenticating users in the official documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/authentication#other-authentication-methods

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to configure login model in providers section in config/auth.php

Some changes have to made in login model also

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

class ModelName extends Model implements \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable
{
    use Authenticatable;
}
```

and in your controller

```
if (!Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])) {
            return redirect()->back()->with(['error' => 'Could Not Log You In!']);
   } else {
        return redirect()->route('routeName');
   }
```

or did you ask to manually authenticate the user from a controller, here is the solution also

```
Auth::login($user);
```

where $user is the login model record of corresponding user